# How to use scrolled to cells in scrollViewDidScroll callback?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have the following function which auto-scrolls my timeline to the last possible cell when the cells are displayed.

```
var onceOnly = false
internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if !onceOnly {
        let indexToScrollTo = IndexPath(row: self.posts.count - 1, section: 0)
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexToScrollTo, at: .left, animated: false)
        let firstPost = posts.first?.timeStamp
        let firstOfFirstMonth = firstPost?.startOfMonth()
        let diff = posts.last?.timeStamp.months(from: firstOfFirstMonth!)
        //self.currentPostMonth = diff
        let monthCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: diff!, section: 0)
        timeline.scrollToItem(at: monthCellIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
        onceOnly = true
    }
}
```

Then I want to detect when my timeline has finished scrolling and once it has, call a specific method on that cell (cell.drawArrow)

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == self.timeline {
        let months = self.posts.first?.timeStamp.startOfMonth().months(from: (self.posts.last?.timeStamp)!)
        let monthCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: months!, section: 0)
        print("cells are",self.timeline.visibleCells)
        if let optionalCell = self.timeline.cellForItem(at: monthCellIndexPath) {
            let cell = optionalCell as! TimelineMonthViewCell
            let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: self.currentPostDate!)
            cell.drawArrow(day: day)
        } else {
            print("cell out of range")
        }
    }
}
```

right now it prints "cells are []", and "cell out of range". So its finding an empty array of visible cells and cannot find the last cell in the range which it is showing on screen. I take this to mean perhaps its trying to execute this before it has loaded the visible cells? Even though I believe the callback should be called after its loaded those considering its scrolled to them?

Anyways how can I do this?

Comment: You are scrolling without animation so there is nothing to detect. The scroll finishes immediately.

Comment: @matt well the scrollViewDidScroll is being called successfully. Im wondering why the scrollView's cells cannot be found with cellForItem(at: ) and why it has an empty array of visible cells

Comment: That doesn’t matter. If you have more work to do after the `willDisplay` code, just go on and do that work. You are getting the scroll callback too soon because you scroll in the middle of `willDisplay` so the callback arrives before you get to the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

The order of events is:

```
let indexToScrollTo = IndexPath(row: self.posts.count - 1, section: 0)
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexToScrollTo, at: .left, animated: false)
// callback
// more work to do
```

So the callback arrives before have finished your work.

There is no animation so you don’t need a callback, and any case this is the wrong callback. If you have still more work to do, just do it.

Comment: Im afraid I still don't understand. So I deleted that callback and moved everything in that callback below collectionView.scrollToItem (where you put //more work to do). It still gives cells are [] and cell out of range. So its still not finding the cells, though I admit I see what you mean now about not. needing the callback

Comment: Well, presumably it isn't all over until all the `willDisplay` calls have been made? You see, the problem is that you are doing all this work in such an odd place. I'm not following what you're trying to do, ultimately. I just tried to explain the question you actually asked.

Comment: understood. Ill try and close this one and open a new question